# raspberry pi b+ python script terminate without error

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I use python to play songs. i used omxplayer for that. but when i running that it will stop and terminate without any error. It runs several loops. sometimes more than 20 times.
Please help me to find the error.

```
#  
#  Copyright 2015  <pi@raspberrypi>
#  
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#  
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#  
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
#  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston,
#  MA 02110-1301, USA.
#  
#  



import os,signal
import thread
import time
import dbus
import subprocess 
import logging
def main():
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s:%(message)s:%(asctime)s',filename='example.log',filemode='w',level=logging.DEBUG)
    out=""
    file="/home/pi/Desktop/song/BnS\ -\ Master\ Sir.mp3"
    path= "omxplayer %s" %(file)
    while(True):
        try:
            logging.info('Started')
            subprocess.call(path,shell=True)
            logging.info('Finished')
            #os.system(path)
        except:
            print "error on subprocess call"
            logging.error("cant open")
    logging.info('end of while')
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: use `check_call()` to raise an exception if the shell returns non-zero exit status

Comment: The logs can be helpful here, what is the last log that you see after the uncatched crash?

Comment: Thank you for reply s. lots of time it is stopped with "Started" log. sometimes its stopped with "finished".